# Armazenando valores de variáveis dentro da função while

Tags: python, python-3.x

Em um exercício eu respondi com esse código:

```
qntd_alunos = int(input("Digite a quantidade de alunos: "))
qnt = 0
while qnt <= qntd_alunos-1:
    MB1 = float(input("Digite a média do primeiro bimestre: "))
    MB2 = float(input("Digite a média do segundo bimestre: "))
    media_semestral = (MB1 + MB2) / 2
    if media_semestral >= 7:
        print("Você foi aprovado")
        print("Sua média semestral é: ", media_semestral)
    else:
        print("Sua média semestral é: ", media_semestral)
    qnt = qnt+1
    if qnt == 1:
        print(qnt, "aluno já recebeu sua média, faltam", qntd_alunos - qnt)

    else:
        print(qnt, "alunos já receberam suas médias, faltam", qntd_alunos - qnt)
```

Esse código calcula a média semestral de cada aluno da classe, mandando uma mensagem apenas aos aprovados, até chegar o último aluno aí o programa fecha.

O que o próximo exercício pede pra transformar esse código e fazer ele calcular a média geral de toda a classe depois de todas as médias individuais serem digitadas a única maneira que eu achei para fazer isso foi armazenando a soma de TODAS as `media_semestral` em UMA variável só e dividindo essa variável pela `quantidade_alunos`. mas eu não consegui achar uma maneira de criar essa variável eficientemente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O caminho é este mesmo, não tem mágica.

```
qntd_alunos = int(input("Digite a quantidade de alunos: "))
qnt = 0
media_geral = 0
while qnt <= qntd_alunos-1:
    MB1 = float(input("Digite a média do primeiro bimestre: "))
    MB2 = float(input("Digite a média do segundo bimestre: "))
    media_semestral = (MB1 + MB2) / 2
    media_geral += media_semestral
    if media_semestral >= 7:
        print("Você foi aprovado")
        print("Sua média semestral é: ", media_semestral)
    else:
        print("Sua média semestral é: ", media_semestral)
    qnt = qnt+1
    if qnt == 1:
        print(qnt, "aluno já recebeu sua média, faltam", qntd_alunos - qnt)

    else:
        print(qnt, "alunos já receberam suas médias, faltam", qntd_alunos - qnt)
print("Média geral ", media_geral / qntd_alunos)
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/VDBtTd). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/oehenywt-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Algorithm/Media.py).

Comment: wooow...era só isso. Eu tava tentando por isso depois da função ou até antes(???) , mas era só colocar dentro XD, muito obrigado...era só isso mesmo.